# Handle customer specific objects in Oracle

Tags: oracle, object, database-schema, handle

the more customers we have for our software solution the more individual oracle objects (Tables, Packages, Functions, etc.) we have in our scheme.
Right now we separate these by giving them identifying names like "X_CUSTOMER1_TABLENAME" e.g. (I know ..... :-( )

This is not very practical when keeping our reference clean and when deploying/syncing our reference with a customer db: One customer would receive the objects of other customers on a deploy.

Is there a common solution to this problem? We were thinking about having a separate scheme for each customer. That way we would have our standard, untouched scheme with the basic functionality and the customer schemes with the individual content.

To make it a bit more concrete: We have around 100 basic tables that make the most of the content/functionality of the software. Each customer might have between 1 -5 additional tables with "custom" data that is used in conjunction with the standard objects in  individual packages, functions etc.
Most of the time only this customer will have these 1-5 tables (e.g. company specific  content that does not make sense for any other company).

I would appreciate any hint or best practise. It's an oldschool relational db.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I am an Oracle DBA with over 20 yrs experience with Oracle, so that makes me "Old School"
My recommendation would be to give each customer his own schema.
Makes things way more manageable; 
 - track activity by schema (for billing purposes)
 - oracle gives you stats on I/O, CPU and space consumption by schema
 - track space usage (if you put their schema in their own tablespace)
 - you can easily move users from one database to another (for growth)
 - when a customer leaves, you backup their schema and drop it
 - you can manage your backups better,  backup active accounts more frequently
   and less active accounts less frequently.
There may be other good reasons, but this short list may be enough.
Your App common tables go in their own schema, but ONLY put the Read Only ones in
this schema;  ANY table that gets modified by the customer, goes into their schema.
You can create a master table list_of_customers, for billing, and security.
but only the App Bus Admin should have access to that one.

Comment: Hey Tom(?) :-)thanks for your reply. This helps me already to make the decision of going the way of schemes per customer. One thing I should explain a bit more though is the fact, that the installations will be made on our customers systems. So I have in mind to have schemes 0001, 0002, etc for each customer IN OUR REFERENCE. But we would then deploy only the scheme for that certain user when installing on their system. So for example for customer 0001 I would deploy the STANDARD and 0001 scheme. Billing is not really a matter for us but something interesting I might have a look at!